# Protovis: layer protovis choropleth map onto google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, protovis

Anyone have an idea how we can overlay the choropleth map (the U.S
obesity rate example on protovis) onto google map (Map of U.S in this
case)? I am trying to tweak the oakland crime spotting example to plot
area to use the choropleth map data. The main problem I face is the
Latitude/Longitude to pixel conversion function:

/* Get the pixel locations of the crimes. */
  var pixels = this.crimes.map(function(d) {
      return m.fromLatLngToDivPixel(new GLatLng(d.lat, d.lon));
    });

As Oakland's crime data is simply a point data:
{ id: "09-900792", code: "Th", date: "2009-03-20T00:00:00-07:00", lat:
37.845066, lon: -122.259251 }

But choropleth map is a polygan shaped stored in a 2D array:
{ name:'Wyoming', code:'wy', borders:[[[-111.137695,45.026951],
[-104.029541,45.034710],[-104.040527,40.996483],
[-111.115723,40.979897],[-111.137695,45.026951]]] },

How do you run the array "borders" through the fromLatLngToDivPixel
function or are there other ways around to layer protovis choropleth
map onto google map?

Source:
choropleth map: http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/choropleth.html
oakland crime: http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/oakland.html

Cheers,
agsub